# iReport - Nullpointer when reading fields from Stored Procedure

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I created a *MySql* Stored Procedure which executes fine and displayed data in Toad MySql and in Report Query window when clicked on Refresh Preview Data.

I am getting message 'Error:null" when clicked on 'Read Fields" button in *iReport*.

Below is the exception written in the log file

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at 
com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.data.ReportQueryDialog.recursiveInterpreter
(ReportQueryDialog.java:2579) at   
com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.data.ReportQueryDialog$FieldReader.run
(ReportQueryDialog.java:773)
```

Query written in Report Query window

```
CALL SP_REPORTS_CONTACT_DETAILS('fc0f18eb-e201-4e77-8f18-ebe2019e778c', 
  'd07318fb-2e1a-42ab-b318-fb2e1a42111')
```

I'm using *iReport 5.5* with *MySql 5.5*

Comment: Have you found a solution ?
When I run the query in Oracle SQL Developer it works fine but I also get the "error:null" when when I click read fields in iReport 5.5.0

Comment: No Andre. Instead I dumped using iReport and started using JasperSoft Studio 5.5.0 which doesnt have this issue. I suggest you to look at the studio as iReport development is being suspended by JasperSoft.

Answer (score 1):

If you change query in existing report, you have to remove all fields and parameters without default expression and then read fields from new query. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Running iReport 5.6.0 on JDK 1.7.60, facing same issue

Interestingly, if I create a new report and paste the query there, it retrieves all fields.

Building a new report isn't a solution, so here is a little hack:

1. Create a new report
2. Paste the query
3. Retrieve all fields
4. Copy the fields from new report and paste in the desired report